# Replace values for several rows based on previous rows

Tags: r, for-loop, group-by, apply, rows

First of all, let my apologize for the not very specific title.

I have a data frame with a structure as per below:

```
alpha <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
            c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
            c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
            c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)) 
colnames(alpha) <- c("key", "group", "v1", "v2")
```

Iterating over the rows of the data frame I want to do the following:

*In cases when v1 is equal to 1 but v2 has not been equal to 1 since v1 was last equal to 1, I want to replace the value of v1 with 0.*

*In cases when v2 is equal to 1 but v1 has not been equal to 1 since v2 was last equal to 1, I want to replace the value of v2 with 0.*

*Furthermore, I want this to be done within each "group", in other words treating rows with different values for "group" as separate.*

*If both v1 and v2 is equal to 1, I want to replace the values of both with 0.*

When done, the data frame should look like this:

```
alpha <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
                c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)) 
colnames(alpha) <- c("key", "group", "v1", "v2")
```

Not very straightforward, sorry! However, I cannot really think of a better way to describe it.

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I started out by using a for loop per the below:

    for (i in 1:nrow(alpha)) {
      if (alpha$v1[i] == 1 & alpha$v1[i + 1] == 1) {
        alpha$v1[i + 1] <- 0
      }
    }

However, I couldn't really figure out how to modify this so that it does not only remove evry other "1", not to mention the problem with there being several "gorups".

In addition, I suspect a for loop isn't the best way since the dataset is quite large, over 1 million rows.